# laravel soketi error, Pusher error: cURL error 7

Tags: laravel, sockets, curl

I can’t figure out how to send a message via a socket, the front connects normally and listens, but the back can’t transmit the message, I keep getting the error Pusher error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 6001 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server ( see https: / /curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http :/ / localhost:6001/apps/1/events

development is carried out in docker containers, I installed the socketi_server container env parameters:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=1 
PUSHER_APP_KEY=asd 
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=asd 
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1 
PUSHER_HOST=localhost 
PUSHER_PORT=6001 
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
```

код

```
class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow { use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

Copy
public function __construct(
    private $user_id,
    private $text
)
{
    //
}

public function broadcastOn(): array
{
    return [
        new PrivateChannel('posts_'. $this->user_id),
    ];
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'postCreted';
}

public function broadcastWith()
{
    return ['message' => $this->text];
}
}
```

If anyone has encountered this problem and solved it please share

I tried to register host as localhost and 127.0.0.1, but curl still gives an error

Comment: Hi Rom, your question is quite open and not specific, the problem couldn't be resolved if you do not provide more informations. are you running in production mode, did you well followed instructions in pusher docs to installed...